# ArcGIS vector tile layer [view:goto-interrupted]: Goto was interrupted error

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, angular, esri-maps-office

I am using vector tile layer in my Angular project to load ESRI map

```
const point = {
            type: "point",  // autocasts as new Point()
            longitude: long,
            latitude: lat
          };
const customData = {
    type: "simple-fill", 
    color: red
}
const circleParam = new esri.Circle({
            center: point,
            radius: circleParams.radius,
            geodesic: true
        });
circle = new esri.Graphic(circleParam, customData);

goToCircle(map, circle): void {
        const circleExtent = circle.geometry.extent;
            map.goTo(circleExtent)
            .catch(function(error) {
                if (error.name != "AbortError") {
                    console.error(error);
                }
                });
    }
}
```

But im getting error as **name: 'view:goto-interrupted', message: 'Goto was interrupted'**

I am loading Map using Vector Tile layer

```
layer = new esri.VectorTileLayer(layerUrl, null);
```

The same circle creation is working fine when map created in Tile layer.

Comment: Which version of the ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript are you using?

Comment: Its  node-package esri-loader : "^2.15.0",

Comment: The issue seems to be https://js.arcgis.com/4.16/dojo/dojo.js not having Spatial reference for 4269 (North America).